# Extends activities with conditions

Tags: android-activity

I develop an application which use scanner library to decode a barcode.
The application can be installed on phone which use zxing library to decode or into other Android specific model which use their own scanner library.

Actually, there are one apk for one type of device. I want to make one apk for all devices.
I want to create one class or one activity by type of library used and call the good one to use.

Is it possible to extends activities with conditions or use this or this activity with condition?

Comment: There must be something different between those devices. Use one `Activity` and check for if that thing exist or not. Then use the result to handle what needs to be done. For example, it could be `if(zxing !=null){//Perform action on zxing} else{//Perform other actions}

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code to get device name :

```
 public static String getDeviceName() {
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        if (model.startsWith(manufacturer)) {
            return capitalize(model);
        }
        return capitalize(manufacturer) + " " + model;
    }
```

and your check will be something like this

```
String zebra = "zebra";
if (getDeviceName().toLowerCase().contains(zebra.toLowerCase())) {
    Scanner_Zebra_Dialog();
} else {
    startScan();
}
```